# Create network using igraph

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I was reading this article and was very intrigued on how it can produce network graph of Mutual Information. I've been trying to figure out to replicate the graph from my dataset, but haven't been able to. Could someone please help me figure this out? I couldn't convert my matrix to vectors for easy reproducibility. I'm working on it.

The paper can be found at http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royopensci/2/2/140270.full.pdf

I'm using `igraph` and `minet.r` packages as explained in the paper.

```
net2 <- build.mim(mi.net, estimator="spearman" )


# create a network
# mi.network<-graph.data.frame(net2, directed=F)
mi.network <- graph.data.frame(net2, directed = F)
V(mi.network)
E(mi.network)
# degree(mi.network)


# mi.network <- watts.strogatz.game(net2, size = 100, nei = 5, p = 0.05)

# deg <- V(mi.network)[degree(mi.network) < 3]

# mi.network.good <- delete.vertices(mi.network, deg)

E(mi.network)$weight <- rep(1:2, length.out=ecount(mi.network))


plot(mi.network, layout=layout_with_kk, vertex.label = NA, edge.weigth = E(mi.network)$weights)
```

But this is not producing what I'm looking for. The graph is shown in page 5 of the paper.

Comment: I don't see any pairing of nodes. To draw a graph, you need to do pairing for the nodes that forms the edges in graph. `igraph` will not directly plot you a graph.

Comment: mi.network contains a matrix of created using `build.mim` which comes from `minet.r` package. This is then used to create the graph. It does plot the graph, but it doesn't do it the way it's explained in the paper in page 5.